# nodejs web application in k8s gets OOM

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, nestjs, fastify

I'm running a nestjs web application implemented with fastify on kubernetes.

I split my application into [Multi Zones](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/multi-zones), and deploy it into different pyhsical location k8s clusters (**Cluster A** & **Cluster B**).

Everything gose well, except the **Zone X** in **Culster A** which has the maximum traffic during all zones.
*( Here is a 2-Day metrics dashboard for **Zone X** during normal time )*

[image: 2-Day Metrics During Normal Time]

---

The problem only happens on the **Zone X** in **Cluster A** and never happens on any other zones or clusters.

At first some 499 responses appear in **Cluster A**'s Ingress Dashboard, and soon the memory of pods suddenly expand to the memory limit one pod after another.

[image: Metrcis During Abnormal Time]

It seems that the 499 status is caused by pods not sending responses to the outer.

At the same time, other zones in **Cluster A** work normally.

For avoiding influencing users, I switch all network traffic to **Cluster B** and everything work properly, Which excludes causing by dirty data.

I tried to kill and redeploy all pods of **Zone X** in **Cluster A**, but when I switch traffic back to **Cluster A**, the problem occurs again. But after waitting for 2-3 hours and then swith back the traffic, the problems disappers!

Since I don't konow how comes, only thing I can do is switching traffic and check is everything back to normal.

I've tried multiple variations of node memory issues, but none of them seems to cause this problem. Any ideas or inspirations of this problem?

---

| Name | Version |
| --- | --- |
| nestjs | v6.1.1 |
| fastify | v2.11.0 |
| Docker Image | node:12-alpine(v12.18.3) |
| Ingress | v0.30.0 |
| Kubernetes | v1.18.12 |

[image: kernal dmesg log]

Comment: Are you using `kubeadm`, `minikube` or Managed Kubernetes Service ?

Comment: That fastify version has this [DDOS known vuln](https://snyk.io/vuln/SNYK-JS-FASTIFY-596516). Could it be the case?

Comment: @matt_j I'm using kubeadm

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon, from network traffic and bandwith, i didn't find any peak. I also tried some DOS attack to my local environment after your advice, but all cannot reproduce the case.
And I will upgrade my fastify version to recommended version for security concerns.